# Post form to Google forms using React

Tags: reactjs, post, google-forms

I added a google form, customized according to website's design, following the instructions from [here](https://blog.webjeda.com/google-form-customize/). and used [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-form) package to post data to google form. It was working in first attempt both at local system and google bucket online, however i made few changes to the form (adding more input fields etc.) and it stopped working even when I reverted to when both the form and code were working, it does not work anymore..

I assume there maybe something wrong with the package or something, can anyone point me in the right direction or suggest an alternative to post to google form? thanks!

here is the form

```
<form className="uk-form contact-form" method="POST" action="LINK TO FORM" onsubmit="return window.submitGoogleForm(this);" >
    // got the action link by doing inspect element on form page
    <div className="uk-grid" data-uk-grid-margin="">
        <div className="uk-width-medium-1-2 uk-row-first">
            <div className="form-field">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Your Name" name="entry.529281403" required="" />
            </div>
            <div className="form-field">
                <input type="email" name="emailAddress" placeholder="Email Address" required="" />
            </div>
            <div className="form-field">
                <input type="text" name="entry.550890690" placeholder="Subject" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className="uk-width-medium-1-2">
            <div className="form-field">
                <textarea placeholder="Your Message Here" name="entry.699777486" rows="9" required></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div className="form-button mt30">
        <button className="readon pill" >Send</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: If someone comes here looking for a way to submit a Google Form from React, here my example of how I do that, hope this help:
[Submit Google Form from React](https://codepen.io/masmerino/pen/EMGvEb) //

Answer (score 1):

For form elements like options and select, the google form will have a hidden  tag at the end of the form. Sometimes you will have to select an option in the form to see that hidden  tag. Copy the name value from that tag to all the options and selects.